# Reading value from Jira custom field in JAVA

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

```
Object object = issue.getCustomFieldValue.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10002");
```

The `customfield_10002` represents Story points in Jira issue.

How will I get the value for this custom field object in Jira?

Answer (score 0):

Custom field object and custom field value is different things. This example will be work.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
Object storyPoints = issue.getCustomFieldValue(ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(10002))
```